# add bootstrap modal after login in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, login, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a boostrap modal just after login in my website.
I have my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#after_login_modal').modal();

});
```

I have my div:

```
<div id="after_login_modal" class="modal bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="after_login_modalLabel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur purus metus, imperdiet id blandit sit amet,
                ornare et nisl. Nullam elit nunc, fermentum id diam eget, auctor ultricies urna. Ut sodales maximus sodales.
                Fusce lacus libero, blandit quis maximus ut, lacinia in velit. Maecenas ligula leo, cursus vel turpis id, fermentum venenatis purus.
                Donec eleifend nisl auctor ex ullamcorper semper. Pellentesque nec varius elit, sed mollis urna.
                Integer suscipit orci id sapien dapibus vulputate. Suspendisse mollis, est non condimentum vulputate, quam quam suscipit nunc,
                eu blandit nibh massa et augue. Curabitur ultrices pretium massa vel egestas.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my action in functions.php:

```
function after_login_display_modal() {
    //stuff
}
add_action('wp_login', 'after_login_display_modal');
```

But I need to integrate everything...and I'm a bit stuck...
Ideal would be load div and javascript only just login.

Comment: hi, any help?...

Comment: Do you want to display the message in the login page or when the user gets to the dashboard?

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much. I want to display when the user gets the dashboard